# Snaketail for windows, how to configure external tool arguments?

Tags: windows, tail

I am using snaketail for windows, however there are some extra features I cannot get my head around when it comes to configuring external tools.

As there are no documentation on the [website](http://snakenest.com/snaketail/) or [github](https://github.com/snakefoot/snaketail-net) I am hoping someone here at stackoverflow might have some tips.

### What I am trying to do

The keyword highlight function lets me filter lines on words, and then trigger and launch external tools which can be configured. I want to trigger a PHP script and send the actual line from the log with the call of the PHP script so I can process it.

There seems to be several variables set in snaketail I can use, however I cant seem to find any way of doing it.

How do I format/configure external tools to send the logline ?

### Here is my attempt so far

There are some fields to configure,

```
name:
command:
arguments:
initial directory:
press shortcut key:
admin rights: [ ]
hide window: [ ]
```

I am trying to configure so that I can send the line from snaketail to a php program so I have confiogured it like this:

```
name: PHP test
command: path-to-php.exe
arguments: path-to-php-file.php
initial directory:
press shortcut key:
admin rights: [ ]
hide window: [ ]
```

The PHP file I have is this:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("f:\output.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, print_r(($_SERVER['argv'])));
fclose($myfile);
```

However I am not able to recieve any data from snaketail other than what I write in arguments myself. There seems to be some variables available, $(LineNumber) etc but I cannot get hold of them.

### Working "external tool" example that plays a sound

To play a sound, you can use vlc of windows media player however I downloaded a little [mini player](http://www.dcmembers.com/skwire/download/swavplayer/) and configured the external tool like this:

```
Name: Play sound
Command: path_to/sWavPlayer.exe
Arguments: "path_to_mp3/file.mp3"
Initial directory:
Press shortcut key:
Admin rights: [ ]
hide window: [ ]
```

This works like a charm, however no data is needed from snaketail in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved!

Well, seems my error was the PHP file so everything was good after all.

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("f:\output.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

ob_start();
var_dump($argv);
$data = ob_get_clean();

fwrite($myfile, $data);
fclose($myfile);
```

Example for external tool with the log line passed over:

```
name: PHP test
command: path-to-php.exe
arguments: path-to-php-file.php "$(LineText)"
initial directory:
press shortcut key:
admin rights: [ ]
hide window: [ ]
```